# Spring Flux. How to buffer objects for a minute and then emmit Mono

Tags: spring-webflux

1. I have a class/method that generates `SomeData` every second.

I need to:

2. collect this `SomeData` into `Somewhere<SomeData>` for 1 minute,
3. after 1 minute take collection and prepare some `ReportObject`
4. and emmit report via `EmitterProcessor<ReportObject>`.

How can I implement that using Flux?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
Flux<SomeData> data = //...
Flux<ReportObject> reports = data
  // if you want 60 seconds windows
  .window(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
  // use a reduce operator to create a report
  .flatMap(window -> window.reduce(..));
```